How to update a Compose TextField during a Baseline Profile generation?
To bypass a login screen in a baseline profile generator, i would like to enter credentials. However the text property seems bugged. Is there a different way to interact with compose TextFields in a BaselineProfile script?
Including a Compose rule seems not working either. This resulted in a compile error.
For example:
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class BaselineProfileGenerator {

    @get:Rule
    val rule = BaselineProfileRule()

    @Test
    fun generate() {
        rule.collect(
            packageName = "com.exaple.app",
            includeInStartupProfile = true
        ) {
            pressHome()
            startActivityAndWait()

            device.findObject(By.text("User name")).text = "baseline_username"
            device.findObject(By.text("Password")).text = "baseline_password"
            device.findObject(By.res("submit")).click()
        }
    }
}

